# Avoiding jQuery conflicts in a dynamically loaded JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I am currently trying to develop a JavaScript application that can be embedded in an existing webpage (which I cannot modify). The application needs a specific version of jQuery.

The script used for loading the application is doing the following:

```
// loading JavaScript needed by my application
(function () {
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>');
    document.write(...); // load other scripts (using jQuery 1.10.2)

    // storing the application's jQuery in a new namespace 
    // to avoid conflicts with other jQuery versions
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript">' + 
        'appJQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>'); // error: jQuery is undefined in IE<10
})();

// initializing the application itself
document.onload = function() {
    // ...
};
```

This works fine in every browser I've tested, except IE < 10. In IE 9 and lower I am getting the error that jQuery is undefined.

Moving jQuery to a new namespace in the `document.onload` function would work for my application but causes conflicts with other scripts on the webpage that includes my application if they need a different version of jQuery.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `document.write`, try creating a `<script>` element and defining an onload handler for that element:

```
(function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
    script.onload = function() {
        var appJQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        // app initialization code
    };
  var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  head.appendChild(script);
})();
```

If you have multiple scripts that depend on one another, you might want to try using a script loader such as [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) or [LABjs](http://labjs.com/).

If you want even greater flexibility in managing dependencies, you can try using a module loader such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Following Hamza's answer, you can use this method of *loading in a different way*:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "../jquery.min.js"     // insert your own jQuery link
s.onload = function() {
    var appJS = jQuery.noConflict(true);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.write` calls would also happen after the document is considered loaded, in which case your `onload` function might fire before the contents of that first function. You want to load the javascript files in a better way, such that *their* onload initiates the application itself.